# Is it possible to go from Eigenvectors to the original nxn matrix from which it was decomposed?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I understand how eigenvectors can be decomposed from a matrix. Now let's say, I have a set of eigenvectors in hand, is it possible to compute the original matrix from it? Also, does it make sense to ask this question?

Comment: **Note:** If two matrices have the same set of eigenvectors (with distinct eigenvalues) then the two matrices commute with each other, that is if the two matrices are A and B, AB = BA. In no way, it means they are same or similar. If you need I can give you a proof.

Comment: Two simple problems with this: you need the eigenvalues as well ($A$ and $2A$ have the same eigenvectors), and there are also situations where the eigenvectors do not span the space, and this means you know nothing about what the matrix does on the unspanned part.

Comment: If you know the corresponding eigenvalues, though, you know that in the basis given by the eigenvectors, the corresponding matrix is the diagonal matrix with entries corresponding to the eigenvalues. Then, applying a coordinate transform back to the cartesian coordinates then gives you the original matrix.

Comment: Assuming that the eigenvectors span your vector space, of course. Otherwise, see the Jordan Normal Form.